# getting sum of count for all date wise data from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

```
Table: call_details
-------------------
userId

phoneNumber

callDate

callType

callDuration
```

Now I want a query to fetch details based on date and type.

Like, I want SUM of total count of callType for the date.

```
28-03-2014 - there are total 1 missed call, 2 incoming call and 5 outgoing calls

29-03-2014 - there are total 0 missed call, 5 incoming call and 10 outgoing calls.

30-03-2012 - there are total 5 missed call, 10 incoming call and 35 outgoing calls.
```

My Query -

```
SELECT `callType`, `callDate`, count(`callType`) as type FROM `tbl_call_details` GROUP BY `callType` ORDER BY `callDate` ASC


callType    callDate    count

OUTGOING    2014-03-28  52
INCOMING    2014-03-30  11
MISSED  2014-03-31  1
```

Result is wrong as its not giving me separate results date wise. Its just picking dates coming in database and displaying everything. I want results separated date wise for all the types with their count on  all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date(`callDate`),
       sum(calltype = 'MISSED') as NumMissed,
       sum(callType = 'INCOMING') as NumIncoming,
       sum(callType = 'OUTGOING') as NumOutgoing
FROM `tbl_call_details`
GROUP BY date(`callDate`)
ORDER BY date(`callDate`) ASC;
```

This puts the values in columns.  If you want them as a string, then you can do:

```
SELECT date(`callDate`),
        concat('there are ', sum(calltype = 'MISSED'), ' missed call, '
               sum(callType = 'INCOMING'), ' incoming call and '
               sum(callType = 'OUTGOING'), ' outgoing calls'
              )
FROM `tbl_call_details`
GROUP BY date(`callDate`)
ORDER BY date(`callDate`) ASC;
```

Comment: The first query is fetching all the records and displaying the count. I don't want each record, I want sum for the date like shown in the question. In this query its displaying all the type count, not the sum of the counts for all dates.

Comment: That would happen if `calldate` were to also contain the time as well.

Comment: callDate is having time as well. So we can't get data like as i said if we have callDate as Timestamp?

Comment: Done. I have casted callDate with date and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you also want to group by callDate like this:

```
SELECT `callType`, `callDate`, count(`callType`) as type FROM `tbl_call_details` GROUP BY `callDate`, `callType` ORDER BY `callDate` ASC
```

Comment: In your query as well i am getting 62 rows, with count. I don't wish to get each count like Incoming - 28-03-2014 - 1, Incoming - 28-03-2014 - 1. I want sum of the numbers for specific date. Like INCOMING - 28-03-2014 - 5 then INCOMING - 29-03-2014 - 10. I want like this, but in this query its giving me one by one count not the sum of count.

Comment: pretty sure this query does what you want, I tested something similar on on other database,  maybe you didn't paste all of it?
SELECT `callType`, `callDate`, count(`callType`) as type FROM `tbl_call_details` GROUP BY `callDate`, `callType` ORDER BY `callDate` ASC